# Print only a part of the answer on python

Tags: python, finance, bitcoin, alpha-vantage

I use an API to have stock or crypto prices. The code I have to execute is this one :

```
resp = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query', params={
    'function': 'CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE',
    'from_currency': 'BTC', 
    'to_currency': 'EUR',
    'apikey': AV_API_KEY
})
resp

resp.json()
```

It gave me this answer :

```
{'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate': {'1. From_Currency Code': 'BTC',
  '2. From_Currency Name': 'Bitcoin',
  '3. To_Currency Code': 'EUR',
  '4. To_Currency Name': 'Euro',
  '5. Exchange Rate': '14161.84281800',
  '6. Last Refreshed': '2020-11-28 09:32:04',
  '7. Time Zone': 'UTC',
  '8. Bid Price': '14161.61726000',
  '9. Ask Price': '14161.62561400'}}
```

But my purpose is to only have the Exchange Rate so to only print 14161.84281800 and not the other infos.

I tried this :

```
print(resp.json('5. Exchange Rate')
```

But I have a SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Is it possible to print only the Exchange Rate or do I have to first execute all the infos and then isolate Exchange Rate to use it for other code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
a={'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate': {'1. From_Currency Code': 'BTC',
  '2. From_Currency Name': 'Bitcoin',
  '3. To_Currency Code': 'EUR',
  '4. To_Currency Name': 'Euro',
  '5. Exchange Rate': '14161.84281800',
  '6. Last Refreshed': '2020-11-28 09:32:04',
  '7. Time Zone': 'UTC',
  '8. Bid Price': '14161.61726000',
  '9. Ask Price': '14161.62561400'}}
k=a.get('Realtime Currency Exchange Rate')
print(k.get('5. Exchange Rate'))
```

first store the json data in a variable then use this program

```
or
```

store json data in "a" variable then use this print

```
print(a.get('Realtime Currency Exchange Rate').get('5. Exchange Rate'))
```

Comment: Ok it works. Thank you. Is it possible to print only Exchange Rate when executing my API or I have to execute and then use this code?

Comment: use this with your program

Comment: a=resp.json() then print(a.get('Realtime Currency Exchange Rate').get('5. Exchange Rate'))

Comment: happy to help you

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

`print(resp.json()['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate'])`

The error you see is because, you didn't end the print statement properly. There is supposed to be two ) brackets.

But even so you'll get an error, because json is like a dictionary within dictionary and so on.

So if you're referencing something from the inner set, you have to follow down the keys.

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `resp.json()` will result in a dictionary. You can access the data like so

```py
exchange = resp.json()
print(exchange['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate'])
```

Use a `try/except` to catch any `KeyError` errors that may occur.

```py
try:
    print(exchange['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate'])
except KeyError:
   print('Could not fetch exchange rate.')
```

Comment: Ok It works, thanks! I want to execute the code every 80 seconds, without any conditions. Do u know if it is possible to do it and save the last X Echange price ?

Answer (score 0):

Simpleset answer.
`print(resp.json()['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']['5. Exchange Rate'])`

you can get all the values using for loop

```
dataArr = resp.json()['Realtime Currency Exchange Rate']
for valuekey in dataArr:
   print(valuekey, dataArr[valuekey])
```